# Finding a set of vectors that spans $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm studying for a midterm and one of the practice problems was:

Inside $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider the vectors:
$\mathbf{v}_1 = (0, 0, 0)$
$\mathbf{v}_2 = (1, -1, 0)$
$\mathbf{v}_3 = (1, 1, 0)$
$\mathbf{v}_4 = (1, 0, -1)$
$\mathbf{v}_5 = (0, 1, 1)$
$\mathbf{v}_6 = (0, 1, -1)$

Which of the following lists span $\mathbb{R}^3$? (There may be more than one answer)
$\text{a)}$ $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2$
$\text{b)}$ $\mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_3, \mathbf{v}_4$
$\text{c)}$ $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_3, \mathbf{v}_5$
$\text{d)}$ $\mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_4, \mathbf{v}_6$
$\text{e)}$ $\mathbf{v}_3, \mathbf{v}_4, \mathbf{v}_5, \mathbf{v}_6$

I thought the answer was $\text{b)}$ and $\text{d)}$, since I thought $n\not=3$ vectors cannot span $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\text{c)}$ contains the $0$ vector. However, the correct answer is $\text{b)}$ and $\text{e)}$. Can someone explain to me why that is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write your vectors a rows of a 3×3 matrix. Row-reduce them, you'll see $v2,v_4$ and $v_6$ have rank $2$. Actually $v_6=v_4-v_2$. Hence they cannot span $\mathbf R^3$.